# Is this a reasonable example of OOP in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to learn Python (3) and I wanted to have a go at some OOP.
I wrote this program, in which two Computer "players" play "Rock Paper Scissors".
It works, but I'd like if someone could have a look and tell me if I have made any silly mistakes!

```
# rock.py
# example of OOP
import random

class Rock:
    def main(self):
        self.Make_players()
        print("Best of Five - Let's play!\n")
        done  = False
        while done == False:
            self.p1.go_player()
            self.p2.go_player()
            print()
            if self.p2.go == self.p1.go:
                print("No winner!\n")
                continue
            else:
                temp = self.check(self.p1, self.p2)
            if temp == False:
                temp = self.check(self.p2, self.p1)
            print(self.message, end = " ")
            print(temp.name + " won this round.")
            temp.scored()
            print(self.p1.name + ": " + str(self.p1.score))
            print(self.p2.name + ": " + str(self.p2.score))
            if self.p1.score == 3:
                self.winner = self.p1
                done = True
            elif self.p2.score == 3:
                self.winner = self.p2
                done = True
            else:
                done = False
                input()
        print("The winner was " + self.winner.name + "!")


def __init__(self):
    print("**** Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!****\n")
    self.winner = False
    self.main()

def Make_players(self):
    temp = (input("What shall we call Player 1? "))
    self.p1 = Player(temp)
    temp = (input("What shall we call Player 2? "))
    self.p2 = Player(temp)

def check(self, p_a, p_b):
    if p_a.go == "rock" and p_b.go == "scissors":
        self.message = "Rock breaks scissors."
        return p_a
    elif p_a.go == "paper" and p_b.go == "rock":
        self.message = "Paper wraps stone."
        return p_a
    elif p_a.go == "scissors" and p_b.go == "paper":
        self.message = "Scissors cut paper."
        return p_a
    else:
        return False

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
        self.score = 0
        self.name = name
        print("Player:", self.name, "created!\n")

    def go_player(self):
        self.go = random.choice(self.choices)
        print(self.name + " chose " + self.go, end = ". ")
        return self.go

    def scored(self):
        self.score += 1

# Main
game = Rock()
```

Comment: This looks more like a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, unless you have a question that can be answered as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Both the Rock class and the Player class have too many responsibilities.  Specifically, you should factor out *printing*, *reading from console*, and the *game loop*.  Or at the very least put the `Rock` main loop in a method called `run`.  It should not start looping from the constructor.

Comment: @Deestan: as this question stays now, I think your comment above deserves to be posted as an answer.

Comment: Thanks jsbueno. I am not very experienced in using this site. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefits of OOP is that you can divide the program into different objects/classes based on roles, responsibilites and concerns.  Currently, both the `Rock` class and the `Player` class have too many responsibilities.

Specifically, you should factor out *printing*, *reading from console*, and the *game loop*.  I would put them in a `Game` class controller.

Whether you factor it out or not, you should also put the `Rock` main loop in a method called run. It should not start looping from the constructor.

In the end, your module level code could look like this:

```
# Main
game = Game()
game.run()
print("Game ended.")
```

Comment: Thanks again. Very helpful for a beginner!